# AWS S3 - Example of searching files in S3 using regex

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cli

How to list the files in S3 using regex (in linux cli mode)? I have the files in s3 bucket like `sales1.txt`, `sales2.txt` etc. When I ran the below command nothing is displaying. Is there a command to list the all the files in S3 bucket with regex?

Command:

```sh
aws s3 ls s3://test/sales*txt
```

Expected output:

```
sales1.txt
sales2.txt
sales3.txt
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? As written, your question is off-topic, as it can be considered broad and unclear. And also "write code for me" without showing any initial effort of your own. Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: You can not do this directly with tools like the AWS CLI - you'd have to do the filtering after the fact (like piping to `grep`).

Comment: What are possible ways to get the list as I expected? I tried with grep but its taking so much time. Could you please point me the correct approach

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the following command

```
aws s3 ls s3://test/ | grep '[sales].txt'
```

Comment: This doesn't really work, as it matches too much:
$ echo returns.txt | grep '[sales].txt'
returns.txt

Answer (score 0):

The accepted solution is too broad and matches too much. Try this:

```
aws s3 ls s3://test/ | grep sales.*\.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to sort this, {aws s3 ls } command is not supporting any regex or pattern matching option. Wr have to use bash commands grep or awk.

```
aws s3 ls s3://bucket/path/ | grep sales|grep txt

aws s3 ls s3://bucket/path/ | grep sales..txt
```